# Using Virtual Directories with FTP

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7.5, virtualdirectories

I've successfully installed and used FTP to transfer files to my server running Windows Server 2008. I've decided to create one FTP site in IIS 7.5 which leads to my \ftproot\ folder, and In an effort to make things a bit more secure, I've selected to isolate users to their physical directory.

I now have the following folder structure for 2 example users:

C:\inetpub\ftproot\LocalUser\JoeBloggs\

C:\inetpub\ftproot\LocalUser\JohnSmith\

In order to show a user files outside of these folders, I understand that I can use Virtual Directories. However, any virtual directory I create under the \username\ folder is invisible to my FTP client. I've selected to display virtual directories in 'FTP Directory Browsing' but it makes no difference - I can't even browse to them through their direct path.

Firstly, is this a good approach to take? Secondly (and most importantly), why can't I view these Virtual Directories through any FTP client?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common issue, but the answer is simple.  You just need to create the physical directories with the same structure as the virtual directories in the FTP root.  Virtual directories are used before physical ones, so its ok that the path is duplicated.  Scott Forsyth has an old (2004) series of blog posts covering FTP under IIS.  The good news is that it still holds true today.

He covers this issue here: [http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/03/10/Mastering-IIS-FTP-*2D00*-Part-2-*2D00*-Virtual-Directories_2F00_Physical-Directories.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/03/10/Mastering-IIS-FTP-_2D00_-Part-2-_2D00_-Virtual-Directories_2F00_Physical-Directories.aspx)